# How can I set the height of a highchart dynamically without setting the width?

Tags: highcharts, height

In the highchart api it states that the way to set the size of a chart is like this:

```
chart.setSize(width, height);
```

The problem is I don't want to set the width, I only want to set the height without having to figure out what the width is of the element. Is there any way to do that?

If I do this:

```
chart.setSize(width, height);
```

It works but I get a few js errors from highcharts, other than that it renders great. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

- set $('#chartcontaierid').height(200) and call $('#chartcontaierid').highcharts().reflow()
- chart.setSize($('#chartcontaierid').width(), 200);